# Pro Guard rules for Tensor flow lite module

Tags: tensorflow, proguard, tensorflow-lite

Hie, I am using tensor flow lite for an android project. when I am running with pro-guard I am receiving the following error and unfortunately, I couldn't find any pro-guard rules of that library

```
org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter: can't find referenced class org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your proguard file:

```
-dontwarn org.checkerframework.**
```

It should fix your problem.